# Launch spark master windows7

Tags: java, apache-spark, windows-7-x64

Using win7-64, jdk8, sparks1.6.2. 
I have spark running, winutils, HADOOP_HOME, etc

Per documentation Note: **The launch scripts do not currently support Windows. To run a Spark cluster on Windows, start the master and workers by hand**. But does not say how?

How do I launch spark master on windows?

Tried running sh start-master.sh thru git bash : `failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:` Even though it prints out **Master --ip Sam-Toshiba --port 7077 --webui-port 8080** - So I don't know what all this means.
But when I try `spark-submit --class "  " --master spark://Sam-Toshiba:7077 target/ .jar` - 
I get errors: 
 WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:
4040: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use

```
WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/01/12 14:44:29 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master Sam-Toshiba:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to Sam-Toshiba/192.168.137.1:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
```

Also tried spark://localhost:7077 - same errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows you can launch Master using below command. Open command prompt and go to Spark bin folder and execute

```
spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

Above command will print like `Master: Starting Spark master at spark://192.168.99.1:7077` in console as per IP of your machine. You can check the UI at http://192.168.99.1:8080/

If you want to launch worker once your master is up you can use below command. This will use all the available cores of your machine.

```
spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.99.1:7077
```

If you want to utilize 2 cores of your 4 cores of machine then use

```
spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker -c 2 spark://192.168.99.1:7077
```

Comment: I am able to start the master successfully, but unable to connect. ` : Starting Spark master at spark://192.168.137.1:7077`. When I try connecting: `>spark-submit --class " " --master spark://192.168.99.1:7077 target/~.jar`
 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 192.168.99.1:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.99.1:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient
: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: 

The currently active SparkContext was created at: (No active SparkContext.)

Comment: Your spark master url is spark://192.168.137.1:7077 but you are passing spark://192.168.99.1:7077 to spark-submit command. Please check.

Comment: Sorry of the goofup - **yes it works now*. Some other errors to still deal with:  `WARN SparkContext: Checkpoint directory must be non-local if S
park is running on a cluster: file:/tmp/log-analyzer-streaming` (it never ends)

Comment: @Sam-T Did you try this? 

`sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")`
`sc.setCheckpointDir("/Users/Samt/CheckpointDirectory")`